# Mapping data between itemgroup

Tags: tfs, msbuild, itemgroup

i have two itemgroup

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Device Include="device1">    
     <Cdname>code1</Cdname>
    </Device>
     <Device Include="device2">    
      <Cdname>code2</Cdname>
    </Device>
    <Device Include="device3">    
      <Cdname>code3</Cdname>
    </Device>
    <Device Include="device4">    
      <Cdname>code4</Cdname>
    </Device>
    <Device Include="device4">    
      <Cdname>code4</Cdname>
    </Device>
    <Device Include="device5">    
      <Cdname>code5</Cdname>
    </Device>
    <Device Include="device6">    
      <Cdname>code6</Cdname>
    </Device>
    <Device Include="device7">    
      <Cdname>code7</Cdname>
    </Device>
    <Device Include="device8">    
      <Cdname>code8</Cdname>
    </Device>
    <Device Include="device9">    
      <Cdname>code9</Cdname>
    </Device>
    <Device Include="device10">    
      <Cdname>code10</Cdname>
```

### upto

```
    <Device Include="device1000">    
      <Cdname>code1000</Cdname>
    </Device>
</ItemGroup>
```

and

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Gpdname Include="d:\gpd\gpd1.GPD">
       <GPDFile>gpd1.GPD</GPDFile>
   </Gpdname>
   <Gpdname Include="d:\gpd\gpd2.GPD">
        <GPDFile>gpd2.GPD</GPDFile>
   </Gpdname>
</ItemGroup>
```

My target is as follows

```
 <Target Name="CopyGPD" Inputs="@(Gpdname)" Outputs="d:\%(Device.Cdname)\drvs\gpd\%(GPDFile)">
```

When copying process is done gpd1.GPD and gpd2.GPD are copied from d:\gpd to
d:\drvs\gpd\gpd1.GPD and d:\drvs\gpd\gpd2.GPD

But i want to copy it to

d:\code1\drvs\gpd\gpd1.GPD

d:\code1\drvs\gpd\gpd2.GPD

d:\code2\drvs\gpd\gpd1.GPD

d:\code2\drvs\gpd\gpd2.GPD

d:\code3\drvs\gpd\gpd1.GPD

d:\code3\drvs\gpd\gpd2.GPD

d:\code4\drvs\gpd\gpd1.GPD

d:\code4\drvs\gpd\gpd2.GPD

d:\code5\drvs\gpd\gpd1.GPD

d:\code5\drvs\gpd\gpd2.GPD

upto------------------

d:\code1000\drvs\gpd\gpd1.GPD

d:\code1000\drvs\gpd\gpd2.GPD

Please help

Answer (score 0):

If you do not insist on the exact order (`gdp1.GDP` and then `gdp2.GDP` for each `Cdname`) this will do the trick (courtesy to [Phil Cupp: MSBuild Tricks I Don’t Want to Forget](http://philcupp.wordpress.com/2009/10/12/msbuild-tricks-i-don%E2%80%99t-want-to-forget/)):

```
<Target Name="Cartesian_Device_GDP">
    <ItemGroup>
        <C Include="@(Device)">
            <A>%(Device.Cdname)</A>
        </C>
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <D Include="@(C)">
            <B>%(Gpdname.GPDFile)</B>
        </D>
    </ItemGroup>

    <CreateItem Include="@(D)">
        <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="CombinedDeviceGDP" />
    </CreateItem>
</Target>

<Target Name="Msg" DependsOnTargets="Cartesian_Device_GDP">
    <Message Text="D:\%(CombinedDeviceGDP.A)\drvs\gpd\%(CombinedDeviceGDP.B)" />
</Target>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Filburt
Thank you for your quick resonse to my question
But still one more issue persist
The Input Output parameter of target is not taking the actual values.It may be due to itemgroup declared inside the target.
Is there any way to sort it out

Comment: See my updated example using the [CreateItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2y3e43x) Task to provide an ItemGroup accessible outside the Target scope.